# Tflite (TF2) trained model running but not detecting in iOS app

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I have trained a pre-model (ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640) using TF2 Object Detection API then exported to an intermediate SavedModel to then convert it in TFlite model, using the following tutorials:
[TF2 Object Detection API](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html), [Running TF2 Detection API Models on mobile](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_on_mobile_tf2.md), [Converter Python API guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api), and, [Edge TF Lite iOS tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/object-detection/docs/tflite-ios-tutorial).

After many work hours I managed to make my model to predict in Python environment and run in the pre-made iOS app from TF lite.

However, after trying many ways of exporting and converting the model I cannot make the model to detect the objects I trained it for to detect.

The following is the instruction for training the model using TF2 API:

```
python3 model_main_tf2.py \
  --pipeline_config_path={pipeline_path}\
  --model_dir={output_model_dir} \
  --alsologtostderr
```

This is the instructions for exporting the SavedModel using TF2 API:

```
 python export_tflite_graph_tf2.py \
 --pipeline_config_path {pipeline_path} \
 --trained_checkpoint_dir {output_model_dir} \
 --output_directory {exported_models_dir}
```

And the following the code to convert the model to tflite from Python API:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(export_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

I have also tried some other alternatives to convert in TF1 like:

```
converter = tf.compat.v1.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(export_dir)
converter.inference_type = tf.compat.v1.lite.constants.QUANTIZED_UINT8
input_arrays = converter.get_input_arrays()
converter.quantized_input_stats = {input_arrays[0] : (0., 1.)}  # mean_value, std_dev
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

and with command line:

```
tflite_convert \
  --saved_model_dir={saved_model} \
  --output_file={output_dir} \
  --output_format=TFLITE \
  --input_shapes=1,640,640,3 \
  --input_arrays='normalized_input_image_tensor' \
  --output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3' \
  --inference_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
  --mean_values=128 \
  --std_dev_values=127 \
  --change_concat_input_ranges=false \
  --allow_custom_ops
```

the result is a 500bytes file. This tflite model looks as follows (in Neutron):

[image: tflite model structure in Neutron]

In the IOS app I adjusted the code this way:

```
  // MARK: Model parameters
  let batchSize = 1
  let inputChannels = 3
  let inputWidth = 640
  let inputHeight = 640

  // image mean and std for floating model, should be consistent with parameters used in model training
    let imageMean: Float = 128
    let imageStd:  Float = 127
```

I have also tried with some other SSD Mobilenet models unsuccesfully. I've been stuck for several days already, I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Does your saved_model work fine for inference? I mean if you load it in Python and try to serve. `converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(export_dir)` should work just fine if you have saved model correctly. May you please share a line how you make save_model?

Comment: Yes, it works fine for inference, The code I used to export the saved_model for inference is: `python3 exporter_main_v2.py --input_type=image_tensor --pipeline_config_path={pipeline_path}  --trained_checkpoint_dir={output_model_dir} --output_directory={exported_models_dir}`

Comment: Is there any public repo where I can checkout those scripts, especially exporter_main_v2.py?

Comment: I used the [Tensorflow object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection), there you can find the exporter_main_v2.py (to test inference), model_main_tf2.py (trainer) and export_tflite_graph_tf2.py (tflite exporter) scripts. I also created a repository with the [COLAB notebooks](https://github.com/jalgalvis/object_detection_tf) I created for this example.

Comment: I do not have access to your data stored on drive. I will take your notebooks as input to try convert standard model. Have you successfully converted standard models from model zoo to tflite?

Comment: I added the files I used from my drive to the repository, and about your question, I made it work only with TF1, but now I need this model to work...

Answer (score 0):

Install tf-nighly and convert saved_model to tflite file
https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly/